# Open close div with on click

Tags: html, onclick, hide, show, css-tables

I have a function that o'clock open and ( should) close a series of div.
Let's say its' an accordion.

```
<div class="cat_table_header" onclick="show_hide_table(this);">
```

The problem is that the first div of this accordion starts always visible, and I would like that this starts closed.
Also if I click it, doesn't close, but if I click another div it closes and open the clicked div.

Any suggestion?

Comment: It will be helpful if you can provide jsfiddle link :)

Comment: Already this answer helped me to find the javascript for it:

Answer (score 0):

This is the javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".cat_table_container").hide();
    jQuery(".cat_table_container:first").show();
});

function show_hide_table (table) {
    table = jQuery(table).parent().find(".cat_table_container");
    if (jQuery(table).is(":visible")) {
        if (jQuery(table).parents(".cat_container").attr("class") != "cat_container cat_container_parent") {
            if (jQuery(".cat_container_parent .cat_table_container").length > 0)
                jQuery(table).hide();
        }
    }
    else {
        jQuery(".cat_table_container").hide();
        jQuery(".cat_container_parent .cat_table_container").show();
        jQuery(table).show();
    }
}
'
```

Many thanks